# MatMul in TensorFlow is slower than dot product in numpy

Tags: numpy, tensorflow

I am observing that on my machine tf.matmul in tensorflow is running significantly slower than dot product in numpy. I have GTX 1080 GPU, and expecting tf.matmul to be at least as fast as when running the code using CPU (numpy).

**Environment Info**

**Operating System**

```
lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.10
Release:    16.10
Codename:   yakkety
```

**Installed version of CUDA and cuDNN:**

```
ls -l /usr/local/cuda-8.0/lib64/libcud*
-rw-r--r-- 1 root      root    556000 Feb 22  2017 /usr/local/cuda-8.0/lib64/libcudadevrt.a
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root      root        16 Feb 22  2017 /usr/local/cuda-8.0/lib64/libcudart.so -> libcudart.so.8.0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root      root        19 Feb 22  2017 /usr/local/cuda-8.0/lib64/libcudart.so.8.0 -> libcudart.so.8.0.61
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root      root    415432 Feb 22  2017 /usr/local/cuda-8.0/lib64/libcudart.so.8.0.61
-rw-r--r-- 1 root      root    775162 Feb 22  2017 /usr/local/cuda-8.0/lib64/libcudart_static.a
lrwxrwxrwx 1 voldemaro users       13 Nov  6  2016 /usr/local/cuda-8.0/lib64/libcudnn.so -> libcudnn.so.5
lrwxrwxrwx 1 voldemaro users       18 Nov  6  2016 /usr/local/cuda-8.0/lib64/libcudnn.so.5 -> libcudnn.so.5.1.10
-rwxr-xr-x 1 voldemaro users 84163560 Nov  6  2016 /usr/local/cuda-8.0/lib64/libcudnn.so.5.1.10
-rw-r--r-- 1 voldemaro users 70364814 Nov  6  2016 /usr/local/cuda-8.0/lib64/libcudnn_static.a
```

**TensorFlow Setup**

```
python -c "import tensorflow; print(tensorflow.__version__)"
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:135] successfully opened CUDA library libcublas.so.8.0 locally
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:135] successfully opened CUDA library libcudnn.so.5 locally
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:135] successfully opened CUDA library libcufft.so.8.0 locally
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:135] successfully opened CUDA library libcuda.so.1 locally
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:135] successfully opened CUDA library libcurand.so.8.0 locally
1.0.0
```

**Code:**

```
'''
Created on Sep 28, 2017

@author: voldemaro

Running on I7/GTX 1080

no MKL
('TF version: ', 'v1.0.0-rc2-15-g47bba63-dirty')
('TF url: ', 'https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/commit/47bba63')
Timing in ms for 2048 x 2048 SVD of type <type 'numpy.float32'> and matmul for 16920 x 2048 of type <type 'numpy.float32'>
numpy default SVD    min:  3956.20, median:  4127.75, mean:  4264.41
TF CPU SVD           min:  5926.43, median:  5951.70, mean:  5961.43
TF GPU SVD           min:  5917.10, median:  6015.87, mean:  6039.63
numpy default .dot product min:  5816.97, median:  5933.43, mean:  5965.22
TF CPU matmul        min: 21939.19, median: 22485.99, mean: 22374.69
TF GPU matmul        min: 22026.52, median: 22109.97, mean: 22199.43
'''

from scipy import linalg;  # for svd
import numpy as np;
import os;
import sys;
import time;

os.environ["TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL"]="2"  # nospam

import tensorflow as tf;
import gc; gc.disable();

NUM_RUNS = 5;
dtype = np.float32;
N=2048;
M =  16920;


def get_tensorflow_version_url():
    import tensorflow as tf
    version=tf.__version__
    commit = tf.__git_version__
    # commit looks like this
    # 'v1.0.0-65-g4763edf-dirty'
    commit = commit.replace("'","")
    if commit.endswith('-dirty'):
        dirty = True
        commit = commit[:-len('-dirty')]
    commit=commit.rsplit('-g', 1)[1]
    url = 'https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/commit/'+commit
    return url

def get_mkl_version():
    import ctypes
    import numpy as np
    ver = np.zeros(199, dtype=np.uint8)
    mkl = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary("libmkl_rt.so")
    mkl.MKL_Get_Version_String(ver.ctypes.data_as(ctypes.c_char_p), 198)
    return ver[ver != 0].tostring()

timeline_counter = 0
run_options = tf.RunOptions(trace_level=tf.RunOptions.FULL_TRACE);


def benchmark(message, func):
    time_list = []
    for i in range(NUM_RUNS):
        start_time = time.time();
        func();
        time_list.append(time.time()-start_time);

    time_list = 1000*np.array(time_list);  # get seconds, convert to ms
    if len(time_list)>0:
        min = np.min(time_list);
        median = np.median(time_list);
        formatted = ["%.2f"%(d,) for d in time_list[:10]];
        result = "min: %8.2f, median: %8.2f, mean: %8.2f"%(min, median, np.mean(time_list))
    else:
        result = "empty"
    print("%-20s %s"%(message, result))


if np.__config__.get_info("lapack_mkl_info"):
    print("MKL version", get_mkl_version())
else:
    print("no MKL")

print("TF version: ", tf.__git_version__)
print("TF url: ", get_tensorflow_version_url())


svd_array = np.random.random_sample((N,N)).astype(dtype);
another_array = np.random.random_sample((M,N)).astype(dtype);

init_OP = tf.global_variables_initializer();


with tf.device("/gpu:0"):
    init_holder_gpu = tf.placeholder(dtype, shape=(M,M));

    specVarGPU = tf.random_uniform((N,N), dtype=dtype);
    S_gpu = tf.random_uniform((M,N), dtype=dtype);
    V_gpu = tf.matmul(tf.matmul(tf.transpose(tf.transpose(tf.conj(S_gpu))), specVarGPU, ), tf.transpose(S_gpu));
    [D2_gpu, E1_gpu,  E2_gpu] = tf.svd(specVarGPU);

with tf.device("/cpu:0"):
    init_holder_cpu = tf.placeholder(dtype, shape=(M,M));
    specVarCPU = tf.random_uniform((N,N), dtype=dtype);
    S_cpu = tf.random_uniform((M,N), dtype=dtype);
    V_cpu = tf.matmul(tf.matmul(tf.transpose(tf.transpose(tf.conj(S_cpu))), specVarCPU, ), tf.transpose(S_cpu));


    [D2_cpu, E1_cpu,  E2_cpu] = tf.svd(specVarCPU);
    V_cpu = tf.matmul(tf.matmul(tf.transpose(tf.transpose(tf.conj(S_cpu))), E1_cpu), tf.transpose(S_cpu));

print("Timing in ms for %d x %d SVD of type %s and matmul for %d x %d of type %s"%(N, N, dtype, M, N, dtype));

def func(): linalg.svd(svd_array)
benchmark("numpy default SVD", func)

config = tf.ConfigProto(allow_soft_placement = True, graph_options=tf.GraphOptions(optimizer_options=tf.OptimizerOptions(opt_level=tf.OptimizerOptions.L0)));
sess = tf.Session(config = config);
sess.run(init_OP);

def func2(): sess.run([D2_cpu.op, E1_cpu.op,  E2_cpu.op]);
benchmark("TF CPU SVD", func2);

def func3(): sess.run([D2_gpu.op, E1_gpu.op,  E2_gpu.op]);
benchmark("TF GPU SVD", func3);

def func1(): np.transpose(np.asmatrix(another_array)).getH().dot(svd_array).dot(np.transpose(another_array));
benchmark("numpy default .dot product", func1)

def func4(): sess.run([V_cpu]);
benchmark("TF CPU matmul", func4)

def func5(): sess.run([V_gpu])
benchmark("TF GPU matmul", func4)
```

Comment: Apparently tensorflow does not optimize "nested" operations, so
tf.matmul(tf.transpose(tf.conj(a)), x) takes significantly longer time than b = tf.conj(a), c = tf.transpose(b), and d = tf.matmul(c, x).

Answer (score 0):

Apparently tensorflow does not optimize "nested" operations, so
tf.matmul(tf.transpose(tf.conj(a)), x) takes significantly longer time than b = tf.conj(a), c = tf.transpose(b), and d = tf.matmul(c, x).

Comment: Tensorflow builds a graph, there is no difference for it to use Python variables in the process or not.

Answer (score 0):

For SVD, the problem is that there is no GPU Kernel for SVD yet. See here: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/11588

This means that SVD has to be computed on the CPU, even if the tensors are instantiated on the GPU. For this reason, there's an overhead for transferring data from the GPU to the CPU for computation, then back to the GPU for storing results.

For matmul on the GPU the problem is in the last line of your bechmarking code: you are not calling func5 but func4 again, so you are benchmarking the TF CPU matmul.

Aside from this, there are a few other things you may want to check in your code:

- there is no need for the `init_holder_cpu` and `init_holder_gpu` vars, as you don't use them
- there is no need to run the global_variables_initializer, as there are no variables
- you are redefining `V_cpu`, using one of the outputs from SVD, so you are effectively running both SVD and the matmul in your test

A slightly cleaned up version of the code looks like:

```
    # ... above is the same
    print("TF version: ", tf.__git_version__)
    print("TF url: ", get_tensorflow_version_url())

    svd_array = np.random.random_sample((N,N)).astype(dtype)
    another_array = np.random.random_sample((M,N)).astype(dtype)

    with tf.device("/gpu:0"):
        specVarGPU = tf.random_uniform((N, N), dtype=dtype)
        S_gpu = tf.random_uniform((M, N), dtype=dtype)
        V_gpu = tf.matmul(tf.matmul(tf.transpose(tf.transpose(tf.conj(S_gpu))), specVarGPU, ), tf.transpose(S_gpu))
        D2_gpu, E1_gpu, E2_gpu = tf.svd(specVarGPU)

    with tf.device("/cpu:0"):
        specVarCPU = tf.random_uniform((N,N), dtype=dtype)
        S_cpu = tf.random_uniform((M,N), dtype=dtype)
        V_cpu = tf.matmul(tf.matmul(tf.transpose(tf.transpose(tf.conj(S_cpu))), specVarCPU, ), tf.transpose(S_cpu))
        D2_cpu, E1_cpu,  E2_cpu = tf.svd(specVarCPU)

    config = tf.ConfigProto(allow_soft_placement = True, graph_options=tf.GraphOptions(optimizer_options=tf.OptimizerOptions(opt_level=tf.OptimizerOptions.L0)))


    def V_numpy():
        np.matmul(np.matmul(np.transpose(np.transpose(np.conj(another_array))), svd_array, ), np.transpose(another_array))


    with tf.Session(config = config) as sess:
        print("Timing in ms for %d x %d SVD of type %s and matmul for %d x %d of type %s"%(N, N, dtype, M, N, dtype))
        benchmark("numpy default SVD", lambda: linalg.svd(svd_array))
        benchmark("TF CPU SVD", lambda: sess.run([D2_cpu.op, E1_cpu.op, E2_cpu.op]))
        benchmark("TF GPU SVD", lambda: sess.run([D2_gpu.op, E1_gpu.op, E2_gpu.op]))
        benchmark("numpy MKL matmul", V_numpy)
        benchmark("TF CPU matmul", lambda: sess.run([V_cpu.op]))
        benchmark("TF GPU matmul", lambda: sess.run([V_gpu.op]))
```

And outputs (ona an i7 and GTX 1070)

```
MKL version b'Intel(R) Math Kernel Library Version 2017.0.3 Product Build 20170413 for Intel(R) 64 architecture applications'
TF version:  v1.4.0-rc1-11-g130a514
TF url:  https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/commit/130a514
Timing in ms for 2048 x 2048 SVD of type <class 'numpy.float32'> and matmul for 16920 x 2048 of type <class 'numpy.float32'>
numpy default SVD    min:  3318.42, median:  3320.40, mean:  3320.40
TF CPU SVD           min:  4576.71, median:  4577.02, mean:  4577.02
TF GPU SVD           min: 14022.59, median: 14172.69, mean: 14172.69
numpy MKL matmul     min:  4500.33, median:  4628.01, mean:  4628.01
TF CPU matmul        min: 15420.19, median: 15664.84, mean: 15664.84
TF GPU matmul        min:   277.80, median:   282.54, mean:   282.54
```

You can see that the GPU version of `matmul` is much faster than any CPU implementation, as expected.